# Advantages of Higher order functions in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

To implement prettified xml, I have written following code

```
def prettify_by_response(response, prettify_func):
    root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
    return prettify_func(root)

def prettify_by_str(xml_str, prettify_func):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
    return prettify_func(root)

def make_pretty_xml(root):
    rough_string = ET.tostring(root, "utf-8")
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    xml = reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
    return xml

def prettify(response):
    if isinstance(response, str) or isinstance(response, bytes):
        return prettify_by_str(response, make_pretty_xml)
    else:
        return prettify_by_response(response, make_pretty_xml)
```

In prettify_by_response and prettify_by_str functions, I pass function make_pretty_xml as an argument

Instead of passing function as an argument, I can simply call that function.e.g

```
def prettify_by_str(xml_str, prettify_func):
   root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
   return make_pretty_xml(root)
```

One of the advantage that passing function as an argument to these function over calling that function directly is, this function is not tightly couple to make_pretty_xml function.

What would be other advantages or Am I adding additional complexity?

Comment: Just a tip, you can replace the if by `isinstance(response, (str,bytes))`

Answer (score 0):

This seem very open to biased answers I'll try to be impartial but I can't make any promise.

First, high order functions are functions that receive, and/or return functions. The advantages are questionable, I'll try to enumerate the usage of HoF and elucidate the goods and bads of each one

## Callbacks

Callbacks came as a solution to blocking calls. I need `B` to happens after `A` so I call something that blocks on `A` and then calls `B`. This naturally leads to questions like, *Hmm, my system wastes a lot of time waiting for things to happen. What if instead of waiting I can get what I need to be done passed as an argument.* As anything new in technology that wasn't scaled yet seems a good idea until is scaled.

Callbacks are very common on the event system. If you every code in javascript you know what I'm talking about.

## Algorithm abstraction

Some designs, mostly the behavioral ones can make use of HoF to choose some algorithm at runtime. You can have a high-level algorithm that receives functions that deal with low-level stuff. This lead to more abstraction code reuse and portable code. Here, portable means that you can write code to deal with new low levels without changing the high-level ones. This is not related to HoF but can make use of them for great help.

## Attaching behavior to another function

The idea here is taking a function as an argument and returning a function that does exactly what the argument function does, plus, some attached behavior. And this is where (I think) HoF really shines.

Python decorators are a perfect example. They take a function as an argument and return another function. This function is attached to the same identifier of the first function

```
@foo
def bar(*args):
   ...
```

is the same of

```
def bar(*args):
    ...
bar = foo(bar)
```

Now, reflect on this code

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

`fib` is just a Fibonacci function. It calculates the Fibonacci number up to `n`. Now `lru_cache` attach a new behavior, of caching results for already previously calculated values. The logic inside `fib` function is not tainted by LRU cache logic. What a beautiful piece of abstraction we have here.

## Applicative style programming or point-free programming

The idea here is to remove variables, or points and combining function applications to express algorithms. I'm sure there are lots of people better than me in this subject wandering SO.

As a side note, this is not a very common style in python.

```
for i in it:
    func(i)
```

```
from functools import partial

mapped_it = map(func, it)
```

In the second example, we removed the `i` variable. This is common in the parsing world. As another side node, `map` function is lazy in python, so the second example doesn't have effect until if you iterate over `mapped_it`

## Your case

In your case, you are returning the value of the callback call. In fact, you don't need the callback, you can simply line up the calls as you did, and *for this case* you don't need HoF.

I hope this helps, and that somebody can show better examples of applicative style :)

Regards